# Create doctrine orm setting for only 1 entity in symfony

Tags: symfony

Im creating a config in my symfony 3.4 that allow to access multiple database
I have set default to automapping to 1 database
then i would like to create 1 orm setting to only 1 entity, not 1 bundle, is that possible?
currently it look like this:

```
connectionName:
            connection: connName
            mappings:
                IpSaBundle: ~
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

When I did the above, I got an error, because in that bundle I have another entity that belongs to default orm setting

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Check here: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-entities-outside-of-a-bundle

```
        # ...
        orm:
            # ...
            mappings:
                # ...
                SomeEntityNamespace:
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    is_bundle: false
                    prefix: App\Entity
                    alias: App
```